# lightbox popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

Im trying to get a gallery working on my page.
Whenever i click my image it opens the full image without the lightbox working properly.

I've put the lightbox.min.css and lightbox.min.js in the right folders and the images in my image folder.

Here is my html code:

Header:

```
    <title>Clein.</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
     user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <link href="assets/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /> 
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><! 
    [endif]-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>


    <body>

    <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="Clein_Logo_v1.png" alt="Logo">

                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <p>Bij mijn schoonheidsinstituut kan je terecht 
                               voor <br /> tal van behandelingen.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#intro">Over</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallerij</a></li>   
                            <li><a href="#work">Behandelingen</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about">Book Online</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
                            <!--<li><a href="#elements">Elements</a></li>-->
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <ul class="icons">
                                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Clein- 
                                140687139893899/" target="_blank" 
                                class="icon fa-facebook"><span 
                                class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                <li><a 
                                href="https://www.instagram.com/_clein._/" 
                                target="_blank" class="icon fa-instagram"> 
                                <span class="label">Instagram</span></a> 
                                </li>
                    </ul>

                </header>

            <!-- Main -->
                <div id="main">

                    <!-- Intro -->
                        <article id="intro">
                            <h2 class="major">Over</h2>
                            <span class="image main"><img 
                            src="images/bummie.png" alt="" /></span>
                            <p>Al van kleinsaf was ik geïnteresseerd in het 
                               lakken van nagels, me opmaken,.. Ook mijn 
                               mama moest dit ondervinden. Deze passie 
                               bloeide verder wanneer ik een richting moest 
                               kiezen. Dit werd natuurlijk bio-esthetiek. 
                               Toen ik afgestudeerd was heb ik nog een 7de  
                               specialisatie jaar gevolgd en aan de hand van 
                               een mini-onderneming en stages ondervonden 
                               hoe het is om in het werkveld te staan. Dit 
                               alles heeft ervoor gezorgd dat "Clein." 
                               ontstaan is.</p>
                            <p>Als productenlijn heb ik gekozen voor het 
                               luxemerk Germaine de Capuccini. Deze staan in 
                               de top 5 van internationale cosmeticamerken. 
                               Met de natuurlijke ingrediënten en 
                               innovatieve verzorgingen wordt uw huid 
                               optimaal verzorgd.</p>
                        </article>


                    <!-- Gallery -->
                        <article id="gallery">
                            <h2 class="major">Gallerij</h2>

                                        <a href="images/img0.jpg" data- 
                                        lightbox="gallery"><img 
                                        src="images/pic0.jpg"></a>
                                        <a href="images/img1.jpg" data- 
lightbox="gallery"><img src="images/pic1.jpg"></a>
                                        <a href="images/img2.jpg" data- 
lightbox="gallery"><img src="images/pic2.jpg"></a>
                                        <a href="images/img3.jpg" data- 
lightbox="gallery"><img src="images/pic3.jpg"></a>
                                        <a href="images/img4.jpg" data- 
lightbox="gallery"><img src="images/pic4.jpg"></a>

                        </article>

 <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

This is not my full code, i only showed you guys some parts of it as you probably already found out.

Comment: Without seeing the full code, my guess is that you are not properly initializing the lightbox plugin in your main.js  Most plugins require you to specify which elements you want the lightbox to be used with.  Check the documentation where you got the plugin for more information.

Comment: @RayDeCramer -- If I were you, I'd write my own lightbox plugin (you can do so with only a few lines of javascript and a few lines of css). You might learn something in the process!

Comment: @duhaime Few lines? Something crappy - yes, sure, but not something nice and fully functional.

Comment: I've written probably half a dozen lightboxes for different apps, and think it's generally a good idea to roll one's own to achieve exactly what's required, but if one prefers to muck about with jQuery or what have you I won't try to interfere

Answer (score 0):

It is just not possible to answer questions like this without seeing live page. First, make sure that your scripts are loaded and check console for any JS message (any error can prevent further execution of JS).

btw, do not use relative paths like `href="assets/css/main.css"`, use `href="/assets/css/main.css"`, this will save you a possible trouble in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try to inspect element, and check the error your JS